# Finding tangent vectors of a surface

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry

I do not understand how the author found the tangent vectors.

M:$\phi(r,t)=(r\cos(t), r\sin(t), \sqrt{1-r^2})$

I tried differenting it, but I don't know how to go from there.

$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial r}=\left(\cos(t),\sin(t),\frac{-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)$ and $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}=\left(-r\sin(t),r\cos(t),0\right)$[image]

Comment: note that the third component of the first derivative is $\frac{-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I realised that I made an error in doing chain rule.